# How to get total by adding all the recycler views rows

Tags: java, android

I have recycler view in my activity and below there is a total cost field which shows the total value comes after adding the values from each row. As shown in the screen below:

[image]
In a recycler view, there is a spinner that shows quantity on selecting a value from spinner it will be multiplied by the MRP like this every same row have some values. I want to add this value and want to show it in the Lower left corner.

So far I am sending MRP value from adapter class to activity using `LocalBroadcatManager` class.
 But every time I selecting data from another row it does not add cost with the previous value
 but it replaces the older value.

Below is my code:

**ProductAdapter.java**

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<ProductsModel> productList;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<ProductsModel> productList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.selectpack_layout,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ProductsModel model = productList.get(position);

    holder.marketName.setText(model.getMarketName());
    holder.productNo.setText(model.getProductNo());
    holder.page.setText(model.getPage());
    holder.mrp.setText(model.getMrp());
    holder.innerPack.setText(model.getInnerPack());
    holder.outerPack.setText(model.getOuterPack());

    List<String> qty = new ArrayList<>();
    qty.add("Select qty");
    qty.add("1");
    qty.add("2");
    qty.add("3");
    qty.add("4");
    qty.add("5");
    qty.add("6");
    qty.add("7");
    qty.add("8");
    qty.add("9");
    qty.add("10");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, qty);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    holder.qtySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    holder.qtySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            int sum = 0;

                String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                if (!item.equals("Select qty")) {

                    int qty = Integer.parseInt(item);

                    int cost = Integer.parseInt(model.getMrp());

                    int val = cost * qty;

                    holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(val));

                    Intent intent = new Intent("msg");
                    intent.putExtra("cost", String.valueOf(val));

                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView  marketName,productNo,page,mrp,innerPack,outerPack,total;
    Spinner qtySpinner;
    Button order;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        order = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order);
        qtySpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qtySpinner);
        marketName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.marketName);
        productNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productNo);
        page = itemView.findViewById(R.id.page);
        mrp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mrp);
        innerPack = itemView.findViewById(R.id.innerPack);
        outerPack  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.outerPack);
        total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.total);
      }
   }
}
```

**SelectPack.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_pack);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    assert ab!= null;
    ab.setTitle("Select Pack");
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    marketSpinner = findViewById(R.id.marketSpinner);
    progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
    products = findViewById(R.id.products);
    totalCost = findViewById(R.id.totalCost);

    products.setHasFixedSize(true);
    products.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    productList = new ArrayList<>();


    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Select market");
    categories.add("Crown");
    categories.add("Long Book A4");
    categories.add("Long Book");
    categories.add("Crown Junior");
    categories.add("Physics");
    categories.add("Chemistry");
    categories.add("Biology");
    categories.add("Universal");
    categories.add("Sketch Book");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    marketSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    marketSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            if(item.equals("Select market")){
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else{

                getData(item);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SelectPack.this).registerReceiver(message,new IntentFilter("msg"));
}

private void getData(String item){

     progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     products.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

     productList.clear();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("name",item)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().post(formBody).url(URL).build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                        if(jsonArray.length() > 0){

                           products.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }

                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String str1 = object.getString("market");
                            String str2 = object.getString("product_no");
                            String str3 = object.getString("page");
                            String str4 = object.getString("mrp");
                            String str5 = object.getString("inner_pack");
                            String str6 = object.getString("outer_pack");

                            Log.d("prod",str2);

                            ProductsModel model = new ProductsModel(str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6);

                            productList.add(model);
                        }

                        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(),productList);
                        products.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final IOException e) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    products.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

    });

}

public BroadcastReceiver message = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String nam = intent.getStringExtra("cost");

          if(nam != null){

              int val = Integer.parseInt(nam);

              totalCost.setText("Total: "+val+".00");

          }

    }
};
```

Someone, please let me know what I am doing wrong or how should I implement it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

why you are using local broadcasts to communicate with activity. Instead, use interface to communicate it will be easy to use.

I found the problem when the item is getting selected you are passing the only current value not all the selected value that's why it is showing the latest value instead of all the value.

You should pass all the selected values from the list, let's say If I select one value, keep that in the separate list or you can manage with a flag in the current list object and when user selects any item then loop through that list and add all the price and pass it to activity.

1. Add one field in ProductsModel called Qty
2. Here is my updated adapter class I have added a comment as well please try this Hope it helps

   public class ProductAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

   ```
   private Context context;
   private List<ProductsModel> productList;

   // add this list
   private List<ProductsModel> selectedProductList = new ArrayList();

   public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<ProductsModel> productList) {
       this.context = context;
       this.productList = productList;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public ProductAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

       View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.selectpack_layout,parent,false);

       ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

       return viewHolder;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       final ProductsModel model = productList.get(position);

       holder.marketName.setText(model.getMarketName());
       holder.productNo.setText(model.getProductNo());
       holder.page.setText(model.getPage());
       holder.mrp.setText(model.getMrp());
       holder.innerPack.setText(model.getInnerPack());
       holder.outerPack.setText(model.getOuterPack());

       List<String> qty = new ArrayList<>();
       qty.add("Select qty");
       qty.add("1");
       qty.add("2");
       qty.add("3");
       qty.add("4");
       qty.add("5");
       qty.add("6");
       qty.add("7");
       qty.add("8");
       qty.add("9");
       qty.add("10");

       ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, qty);

       dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

       holder.qtySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

       holder.qtySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

               int sum = 0;

               String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

               // add this line
                adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

               if (!item.equals("Select qty")) {

                   // add this line
                   model.setQty(Integer.parseInt(item));
                   selectedProductList.add(model);
               }

               int val = 0;
               for(int j = 0; j < selectedProductList.size(); j++){

                   ProductsModel model  = selectedProductList.get(i);
                   int mrp = model.getMrp();
                   int qty = model.getQty();

                   val = val + (mrp * qty);
               }

               holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(val));
               Intent intent = new Intent("msg");
               intent.putExtra("cost", String.valueOf(val));
               LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return productList.size();
   }



   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       TextView marketName,productNo,page,mrp,innerPack,outerPack,total;
       Spinner qtySpinner;
       Button order;

       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           order = itemView.findViewById(R.id.order);
           qtySpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qtySpinner);
           marketName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.marketName);
           productNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productNo);
           page = itemView.findViewById(R.id.page);
           mrp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mrp);
           innerPack = itemView.findViewById(R.id.innerPack);
           outerPack  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.outerPack);
           total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.total);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Can you please implement this in code actually I am not getting the how to loop through every row and add the value.

Comment: @Digvijay I have updated my answer please have a look and let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Let me check your solution and will get back to you

Comment: I have tried your solution it is not adding values properly...